# Adb connects and disconnects after 2 seconds

Tags: adb

I am running an AVD through Genymotion. Also, I have installed Kali Linux VM in my windows laptop. I am trying to connect to the android through the terminal

> adb connect 192.168.104.103

and it connects successfully. Then I have tried to install an application with

> adb install test.apk

and it is also installed successfully.

**BUT**, when I am trying to execute the command pull I am getting the error:

> adb: error: failed to get feature set: no devices/emulators found

```
adb connect 192.168.104.103
already connected to 192.168.104.103:5555
adb devices
List of devices attached
device
192.168.104.103:5555
./adb pull /data/data/com.android/providers.userdictionary/databases/user_dict.db
adb server version (39) doesn't match this client (41); killing ...
* daemon started successfully
adb: error: failed to get feature set: no devices/ emulators found
adb devices
List of devices attached
adb server version (41) doesn't match this client (39); killing ...
* daemon started successfully
adb devices
List of devices attached
adb connect 192.168.104.103
connected to 192.168.104.103:5555
adb devices
List of devices attached
device
192.168.104.103:5555
./adb pull /data/data/com.android/providers.userdictionary/databases/user_dict.db
adb server version (39) doesn't match this client (41); killing ...
* daemon started successfully
adb: error: failed to get feature set: no devices/ emulators found
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Robert's instructions problem solved:

> The console output shows that you have two different and incompatible
> adb versions installed. Usually Genymotion comes with an own adb
> version, make sure that you are not using this potentially outdated
> version. Better to have only one adb version (the newer one)
> installed. Then such problems can not occur.

Comment: My comment only describes why the error occurs. It would be nice if you could add what you actually did to solve the problem.

Comment: Following your comment, I changed the android-sdk version in path /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools and I added the latest. I downloaded from here: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r30.0.5-linux.zip

Answer (score 1):

Genymotion is designed to work without Android SDK installed, therefore it contains it's own version of `adb`. If two different versions of adb are installed on the same computer and used alternating then this leads to the problem that `adb server version doesn't match this client`.

If you have Android SDK installed as well as Genymotion there is a very simple fix:

In Genymotion program open the **Settings** dialog and select the section **ADB**.
Now enter the path to your installed Android-SDK and close the settings dialog.

Afterwards Genymotion uses the adb version from Android-SDK instead of it's own version. As long as you don't have a third or fourth version of adb installed this should fix the problem.

[image]